# How to add different elements (text, arrow, shapes...) to each page of an ATLAS composition

Tags: qgis, layouts, atlas

I'm doing an ATLAS composition of a photographic itinerary. That means that I made a hiking route and I took photos in different places and now these places are representing in the map (as a point layer). But... what I want is to add an arrow pointing out the direcction where I took the photo. The thing is as an ATLAS works, its pages follow the layer of the itinerary, so when I go to the next page of the atlas, the arrows that I've drawn in page 1 are still there, in page 2. How can I order to qgis that I want different arrows for each page.[image]

Comment: You should adapt your point symbols accordingly.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking for the possibilities describes at point 25 in the following tutorial: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/automating_map_creation.html